# Git - I can't delete folder

Tags: git, mingw, mingw-w64

I can't delete my folder in GIT. I don't know why, but I get error `fatal: pathspec <...> did not match any files`

```
falau@DESKTOP-N69FOT3 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Projekty/cPlusPlusProjects/bazaPracownikow/bazaPracownikow (master)

$ ls

bazaPracownikow/    bazaPracownikow.sdf    bazaPracownikow.sln    Debug/

falau@DESKTOP-N69FOT3 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Projekty/cPlusPlusProjects/bazaPracownikow/bazaPracownikow (master)

$ git rm --cached -r Debug/

fatal: pathspec 'Debug/' did not match any files
```

Comment: has "Debug/" already been tracked by Git?

Comment: Directories aren't first-class citizens in git, but you should really google this first.

Comment: Open CMD & type these commands...
`C:` > `CD "location"` Ex: CD `"C:\GitHub"` > `rmdir FolderName /S` Ex: `rmdir GitHub /S`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably empty. Git doesn't track directories, so if it's empty it won't know of any files to delete. You can just delete it with `rm` or `rmdir` instead. *Or* it may have ignored files in it, in which case you shouldn't delete it if you want those ignored files.

Comment: falau@DESKTOP-N69FOT3 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Projekty/cPlusPlusProjects/bazaPracownikow/bazaPracownikow (master)
$ cd Debug/

falau@DESKTOP-N69FOT3 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Projekty/cPlusPlusProjects/bazaPracownikow/bazaPracownikow/Debug (master)
$ ls
bazaPracownikow.exe*  bazaPracownikow.ilk  bazaPracownikow.pdb


There is files in dir. I have question - if I create .gitignore file with ignoring everything without *.cpp and *.txt then I can't delete ignoring files from my repo?